# How to install BIOS on samsung laptop

Tags: ubuntu, bios

My laptop BIOS is broken, when I hitting <kbd>F2</kbd> key it enter GRUB... Maybe it replaced by Grub2. So I can't set boot order from USB boot.

Now I can't get into Fedora 17 ( cos I converting sda disk filesystem to msdos using Gparted).

How can I recover or install BIOS ?

I just want to set boot order from USB to boot and install Ubuntu, but now I can't.

27.Aug, I tried the Plop(v5) in grub, but failed... show error:"zImage is not supported".

Laptop Specs: Samsung 530U3C-A01 ultrabook, 4GB RAM, 500GB HDD and 24GB SSD in motherboard, currently running Fedora17 in 24GB SSD.

Comment: This is essentially the same question as your [previous one](http://superuser.com/questions/466242/cant-enter-the-bios-on-samsung-laptop-after-installing-fedora-17). Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Comment: What kind of notebook is it?  Is F2 actually the key to get into the BIOS?

Comment: Its samsung ultrabook 530U3C-A01. F2 key is enter BIOS, but now, it's unable to enter.

Comment: Why the hell is this closed? I have the same issue.
Too localized? NO, certainly it's not. Recently stackoverflow gets too... "closed". We're all using Google to search it anyway.
Too localized... Yeah, right.

In topic: The issue here is that BIOS is probably broken. I took hdd out of my laptop and BIOS still does not load. I'll take my Samsung notebook to reseller (warranty should include this kind of issues), I see no other way.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't sound like your BIOS is broken at all... You are talking about the bootloader which happens after the BIOS stage.

You may have deleted the partition with the OS on that you want - I can't really help there as I am not a GRUB expert / not sure how to configure it, but, if you simply want to install Ubuntu, try pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> which is usually the boot menu button, or <kbd>Delete</kbd> to get in to the BIOS... Also, <kbd>F10</kbd> sometimes works.

Comment: Any keys I tried, only <kbd>F10</kbd> is working, it's boot menu, but there hasn't "boot from USB" option.